# How to deploy a serverless code into a stage in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

To deploy a serverless project into a stage of a service, following command can be used

> serverless deploy --stage dev

*Extracted from the docs*
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying/

However when above command is used to deploy a service, it creates a new service with name **dev-aws-nodejs** in API Gateway.

Is it possible to create a service with name **aws-nodejs** and have different stages like dev, stag, prod etc.. Therefore, when you run the following command

> serverless deploy --stage stag

A new stage called **stag** will be created under service **aws-nodejs**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design the current version of serverless framework doesn't support this feature. But the version 0.5.6 had been designed to deploy multiple stages into api single api gateway project. Following open issues are related to this. Some have suggested few workarounds.

[AWS API Gateway stages and names are separated](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2445)

Issue below, mainly highlight different services into same api gateway. But it also has some comments related to your query as well.

[Deploy many micro/nano services to one API Gateway](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3078)

**Update:**

In the recent release of serverless (v1.19), they have mentioned that they have started working on a solution for this.

[Serverless v1.19 Changelog](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1.19.0/)